# How to set static or dynamic ip address on linux?

Tags: linux, internet-connection, ip-address

I don't know a priori if a DHCP server would be present in the environment. So, I would like to set a dynamic IP address if there is a DHCP server, instead, I would like to set a static IP address if there isn't any DHCP server. Automatically.

I have just one network interface, eth0.

I tried to edit the /etc/network/interfaces like that:

```
auto eth0 eth0:1

iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.10
```

but it did not work.

I also tried this way

```
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.10
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

but I had no success.
I also tried to use the default iface:

```
iface default inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.10
```

Can you explain to me what is the default iface? when do you have to use it?

any idea about how to have a static or dynamic IP address with just one network interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1  
iface eth0:1 inet static  
address 192.168.1.150  
netmask 255.255.255.0  
gateway 192.168.1.10
```

Comment: it doesn't work. It is the same thing I already tried

Comment: They should be on separate stanzas, but when you say they don't work, what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: I'm testing if I could reach a computer, with a static ip address, from another computer, just connecting each other with a LAN without passing through a router. The 2 computers are in the same subnet.

Comment: and if apply that configuration I cannot reach the computer

Comment: From inside, what does the machine say? Is the network DHCP or static, and what does `ip route show` say?

Comment: I'm thinking it may just be a routing issue, though I'd like to see what the logs on your machine say..

Comment: ip route show: default via 192.168.1.10 dev eth0 and 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.150

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9186/discussion-between-nickw-and-gappa)

Comment: BTW, if the other machine (the one you can't ping) is a windows 7 machine, it is normal that it doesn't respond to pings!

Comment: nooooooo come on!!!!!!!!!!! are you kidding me?!?!??!?!!?!?!? I cannot explain to you my mood right now!!!!!!!!!! I'km shocked!!! I'm more a unix guy!!!!

Comment: I'm very to have wested your time yesterday! anyway the machine is a windows 8!!!!

Comment: Not a problem at all, these sort of little things are absolutely normal :)